# can I make apacite citation always use et al. for more than two authors?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, author-number

The apacite package documentation here:

http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf

states that whenever citing more than two authors (but less than six), the first time the full will appear, but from thereon, citing again the paper will lead to an et al suffix after the first author.

Is there a way to make apacite use et al. already from the beginning whenever citing more than two authors?

Also, is there a way to make apacite use "and" instead of "&" between author names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a universal flag that can be set to control whether or not a full list of authors is used the first time. The list of authors is controlled by the `\BCA` macro in `\@@cite`. A relatively simple patch is all that is required. We need to change

```
\def\BCA##1##2{{\@BAstyle ##1}}%
```

into

```
\def\BCA##1##2{{\@BAstyle ##2}}%
```

You can just copied the macro and make the change, but I used the [`regexpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch).

As for replacing `&` with `and`. This is controlled by the `\BBAA`, `\BBAB`, and `\BAnd` macros:

```
\newcommand{\BBAA}{\&}  % between authors in parenthetical cites and ref. list
\newcommand{\BBAB}{and} % between authors in in-text citation
\newcommand{\BAnd}{\&}  % for ``Ed. \& Trans.'' in ref. list
```

You can change them with `renewcommand`, but you have to do the redefinition after `begin{document}` because the package loads language settings with `AtBeginDocument`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@@cite}{\def\BCA##1##2{{\@BAstyle ##1}}}{\def\BCA##1##2{{\@BAstyle ##2}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}  % between authors in parenthetical cites and ref. list
\renewcommand{\BBAB}{and} % between authors in in-text citation
\renewcommand{\BAnd}{and}  % for ``Ed. \& Trans.'' in ref. list

\cite{inproceedings-full}

\cite{inproceedings-full}

\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any updates for new versions?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use `\shortcite` instead of `\cite`

Answer (score 0):

[biblatex-apa](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa) will do the trick, add this to the beginning of your document:

```
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
...
\printbibliography
```

Citing with `\parencite` will give you the following results:

- 1  Author  `(Einstein, 1926)`
- 2  Authors `(Einstein & Newton, 1927)`
- 3+ Authors `(Einstein et al., 1923)`